# Reusing the same connection to read uncommited transaction

Tags: postgresql, transaction, pgbouncer

My question is similar to: [how to spy on a transaction that is not yet committed in postgres for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195088/how-to-spy-on-a-transaction-that-is-not-yet-committed-in-postgres-for-debugging)

What I tried:

1. I start a pgbouncer instance, and set the max-db-connection to 1
2. From my node application, i connect to pg-bouncer
3. I `BEGIN` a transaction, and inserted a few rows, i.e: `INSERT INTO USERS VALUES ('john')`
4. I end the application without `COMMIT`
5. I connect to pgbouncer from another client (i.e: Datagrip)

Expected: I can continue from the uncommitted transaction, and `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name = 'john'`, would retrieve the rows.

But what happens is that PgBouncer would close the connection ( `closing because: unclean server (age=0s)`) when a client connects, since it knows that there is an uncommited transaction. Is there a way to make this hack work with/without using PgBouncer?

Answer (score 0):

You can only see uncommitted data modifications withing the transaction that performed them, so your client code would have to use the same transaction for everything. This sounds a lot like you are going to end up with long running transactions, which is a very bad idea in database, particularly in PostgreSQL.

I recommend that you approach this in a different way. Add a column `committed` to the table that you set to `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or something similar). Then you don't have to keep transactions open for a long time, and other transactions that choose to do so can simply `SELECT` “uncommitted data”.